# Webrtc MediaStreamTrack.CreateVideoTrack return track with state ended

Tags: c#, video, uwp, webrtc

I am implementing webrtc using the sdk from this repo:

https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/webrtc-uwp-sdk

My implementation works well most of the times but I have some problems when creating and hanging up calls in quick succession. Sometimes when calling MediaStreamTrack.CreateVideoTrack I get a track with state ended which, as I understand it, means I will not get any media from this track. When hanging up the call I do dispose the previous peerconnection as well as disposing tracks. I suspect that maybe the camera is shut down in the background after I have disposed all my resources, however I find that a bit strange.

The code that creates the videotrack looks like this:

```
var factoryConfig = new WebRtcFactoryConfiguration();
                    factoryConfig.AudioCaptureDeviceId = MediaDevice.GetDefaultAudioCaptureId(AudioDeviceRole.Default);
                    factoryConfig.AudioRenderDeviceId = MediaDevice.GetDefaultAudioRenderId(AudioDeviceRole.Default);

                    var _factory = new WebRtcFactory(factoryConfig);
var cameraDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
                    var frontFacing = cameraDevices.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Panel.Front);
                    var videoParams = new VideoCapturerCreationParameters()
                    {
                        Name = frontFacing.Name,
                        Id = frontFacing.Id,
                        EnableMrc = false
                    };
                    var mandatoryConstraints = new List<Constraint>() {
                        new Constraint("maxWidth", "1280"),
                        new Constraint("minWidth", "1280"),
                        new Constraint("maxHeight", "720"),
                        new Constraint("minHeight", "720"),
                        new Constraint("maxFrameRate", "30"),
                        new Constraint("minFrameRate", "15")
                    };
                    IReadOnlyList<Constraint> optionalConstraints = new List<Constraint>();
                    var videoCapturer = VideoCapturer.Create(videoParams);
                    var options = new VideoOptions();
                    options.Factory = _factory;
                    options.Capturer = videoCapturer;
                    options.Constraints = new MediaConstraints { Mandatory = mandatoryConstraints, Optional = optionalConstraints };
                    _videoTrackSource = VideoTrackSource.Create(options);
                    _selfVideoTrack = MediaStreamTrack.CreateVideoTrack("SELF_VIDEO", _videoTrackSource);
```

The code I use to shut down the call looks like this:

```
                if (_peerConnection == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _peerConnection.OnIceGatheringStateChange -= PeerConnection_OnIceGatheringStateChange;
                _peerConnection.OnIceCandidate -= PeerConnection_OnIceCandidate;
                _peerConnection.OnTrack -= PeerConnection_OnTrack;
                _peerConnection.OnRemoveTrack -= PeerConnection_OnRemoveTrack;
                _peerConnection.OnIceConnectionStateChange -= PeerConnection_OnIceConnectionStateChange;
                _peerConnection.OnNegotiationNeeded -= PeerConnection_OnNegotiationNeeded;

                if (_remoteVideoTrack != null)
                    _remoteVideoTrack.Element = null;
                if (_selfVideoTrack != null)
                    _selfVideoTrack.Element = null;

                (_selfVideoTrack as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
                (_selfAudioTrack as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
                (_remoteVideoTrack as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
                (_remoteAudioTrack as IDisposable)?.Dispose();

                _selfVideoTrack = null;
                _selfAudioTrack = null;
                _remoteVideoTrack = null;
                _remoteAudioTrack = null;

                (_peerConnection as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
                _peerConnection = null;

                GC.Collect();   //Not pretty but it seems neccessary at this point to close camera
```

I have based a lot of my code on the PeerCC sample in the repository mentioned at the beginning of the post:

https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/PeerCC/blob/9bcdc04a9d0d8f8b66e313272312ebb608154aa0/ClientCore/Signalling/Conductor.cs

If anyone has any idea of what I might be doing wrong I would be happy to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the cause of the issue. However I managed to solve it by simply implementing a retry behaviour so that if I get a track with state ended upon creation I simply retry a number of times. So long this have been successful. If it fails the first time it usually succeeds the second or third time.

I know this is not the best solution to my problem however I thought I should add it if it helps anybody in the same situation.